# UIScrollView did zoom but subview stay unchanged

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I'm currently developping an iPad app and I need a "Slideshow"

So I create a first UIScrollView which will be used as pager and in the viewDidLoad I use a "for" loop to put the content in the UIScrollView.

Here is the loop :

```
for (int i = 0; i < self.thumbs.count; i++) {
    UIScrollView *subScroll = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.ThumbsSlider.frame.size.width * i, 0, self.ThumbsSlider.frame.size.width, self.ThumbsSlider.frame.size.height)];
    [subScroll setDelegate:self];
    [subScroll setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [subScroll setBouncesZoom:YES];
    [subScroll setClipsToBounds:YES];
    [subScroll setContentMode:UIViewContentModeCenter];

    subviewImage          = [[AsyncImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0 , 0, subScroll.frame.size.width, subScroll.frame.size.height)];
    subviewImage.contentMode            = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    subviewImage.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    subviewImage.image    = [UIImage imageNamed:@"no-image.jpg"];
    subviewImage.imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[self.thumbs objectAtIndex:i]];

    [subScroll addSubview:subviewImage];

    subScroll.minimumZoomScale = 1.0;
    subScroll.maximumZoomScale = 3.0;

    [[subScroll delegate]viewForZoomingInScrollView:subScroll];

    [self.ThumbsSlider addSubview:subScroll];
}
```

When I launch the app on my iPad, there is no crashes.
But, when I try to zoom, the contentSize of my subScroll change but the subviewImage doesn't zoom !

Can someone explain me why ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: try setting `viewForZoomingInScrollView:` to `subviewImage`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this function in your controller

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    for (UIView *imageView in scrollView.subviews)
    {
        if ([imageView isKindOfClass:[AsyncImageView Class]])
        {
            return imageView;
        }
    }

    return nil;
}
```

And remove below line from loop:

```
[[subScroll delegate]viewForZoomingInScrollView:subScroll];
```